# Android Studio Bumblebee, HMS Toolkit Not Working, why?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, toolkit

I installed the latest version of android studio and HMS toolkit.
When I turn on the HMS toolkit it crashes.
What could be the problem?

Versions:
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 2
HMS Toolkit 6.2.0.300

hms problem：

[image]

Comment: It reads: Android Studio versions [`3.4.1-4.2.2`](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/overview-0000001050060881).

Comment: HMS toolkit is not supporting Android Studio Chipmunk also, and when I tried with Arctic Fox I am getting Internal Server error.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your feedback. The Toolkit R&D team is now adapting to the latest Android Studio version and is expected to release in June.

Comment: It is still not available, I am checking with Android Studio Chipmunk.

Comment: hello @zhangxaochen please advise if any ETA. Being a while.